# chmod on /System/Library/ in Mac Snow Leopard - Now Cannot Open Terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, chmod

I was trying to run a command to fix a different issue, but when I cut and pasted the string there was a space in it and this is what was run:

sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/

Now when I try to open terminal, it just sits there with a blank screen and nothing loads.  This started almost immediatey after I ran that command.  Any ideas how to reverse this back to previous permissions?  I did try repairing disk permissions, but that does not seem to have solved it.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Start your mac in [single user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492). Than you get a commandline prompt where you can enter

```
chmod 755 /System/Library
```

Comment: Note that you'll first need to enter `mount -uw /` in order to get write access to the volume.

Comment: @Gordon: oh yes, of course

Answer (score 0):

Open /System in Finder (Go - Go to Folder..), select 'Library' folder, Cmd+I, click lock icon to unlock settings (enter your pwd), set permissions.